# Prevent StackOverflowException in Property-Definition in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, stack-overflow

In my class a 'Sub Process' is responsible to produce some values in a property (list(of integer)). This sub process should always be called when the value of the property is got.

```
MustInherit Class TestClassBase
   Private _OutputList As New List(Of Integer)

   Public Property OutputList() As List(Of Integer)
       Get
           Me.Process()
           Return _OutputList
       End Get
       Set(ByVal value As List(Of Integer))
           _OutputList = value
       End Set
   End Property

   Public MustOverride Sub Process()
End Class


Class TestClass
   Inherits TestClassBase

   Public Overrides Sub Process()
       OutputList.Clear()
       OutputList.Add(1)
       OutputList.Add(2)
       OutputList.Add(3)
   End Sub
End Class


Module ModuleTest
   Sub Main()
       Dim tmpList As New TestClass
       tmpList.Process()
   End Sub
End Module
```

Calling Me.Process in the the Get-Part of the Property produces an StackOverflowException. Because of the TestclassBase as Mustinherit and the need of implement the 'Sub Process' in an inherited class I don't have access to the Private _Outputlist.

What is the most elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Change the  _OutputList access modifier from Private to Protected.  Having  a property getter modify a field is a very bad idea btw, property getters should never mutate the state of an object.  Otherwise the basic reason you got into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `OutputList.Clear()` in `Process` that calls the `OutputList` getter. That getter then calls `Process` again, which then calls `OutputList.Clear()` again.

This call sequence will continue until you run out of stack and generate the exception.

You need to stop and think about what you are actually trying to achieve here (hint, doing processing in a getter is generally a bad idea) and rethink your design.